# How do I import behaviors into Expression Blend?

Tags: silverlight, import, expression-blend, behavior

I'm trying to import behaviors in to blend, can anyone help me?

I'm a designer not a coder so would like to know the easy import rout for this in Blend?

Comment: Please. Be more polite -> "How do to import behaviors into expression blean?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, so there are couple of options:

1. *(The option Christian mentioned)*. Make sure the library in which your behaviours are in is referenced by your project. The Asset Gallery should auto populate with those behaviours.
2. *(The option dave mentioned)*. Add the source code for the behaviours in your project or somewhere in your solution referenced by the Silverlight project.
3. Drop your Behaviours library into the following directory: 
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 3\Libraries\Silverlight\v3.0 (location varies based on your machine configuration)
   Once you do that and restart Blend it should pick up on those Behaviours. (But give it a minute, there's a lag to scan these directories)

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm a designer not a coder so don't really know what all this means. I really want to find out from a design perspective how to import behaviors into Blend much like how I would import brushes and shapes in photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

If your project references a custom Behavior, it should show up in the list of behaviors.  The behavior must be in a class file in your project, or your project must reference an assembly that contains the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on this, custom behaviors come as libraries or source code. If you have a library (a file with the extension .dll), you have to add a reference to that dll to your project. You can do that by going to the project pane, right clicking on the project node and selecting Add Reference.
If you have a SketchFlow project, you may have to add the behavior to both the player project and the screens project.